# "The App Name you entered has already been used" even though I just created the app

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, game-center, gamekit

I am trying to create my app on iTunes Connect, so I can add my game center features. When I reach the screen where I fill in the default language, app name, sku number, and bundle id, I receive an error message:

```
The App Name you entered has already been used.
```

Does this mean someone else has used this app id? I couldn't find the an app with this name on the iTunes Store anywhere.

I just started creating the app on iTunes Connect, so I definitely didn't use it.

Is there some way to verify that this is not a bug, and someone else has chosen the name?

Comment: What was the name you used?

Comment: I would rather not say, since I want to use it.

Comment: Then, without the name to check, we're a little hamstrung. It could be a bug or it could be used and your google-fu isn't powerful enough to unearth it. I suggest you contact Apple since they will be the only ones who can provide a definitive answer and presumably you won't mind giving _them_ the app name.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you created an entry for the first App in iTunesConnect, even if it was never submitted or uploaded, then that name is locked to that iTunesConnect App permanently. That means if another user have choose same name already but still not upload and release app than you will not able to find on itunes store.
See [Apple app store tips](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html)

> The name you select for your app is perhaps one of the most important aspects to marketing your app and can **distinguish** your app on the App Store.
>   *If you submit an app name which is already in use within the same geography in which your app is sold, you will be prompted to enter another name.*

You can find more info in [iTunesConnect Developer's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iTunesConnectGuide)

Comment: How would you know who took that name ?

Comment: We cant know who have took the name.. Apple knows only ;)

Comment: How can I edit my previous locked app, as it is not showing in appStore

Comment: You can't edit app name after create your app in iTunesConnect

Answer (score 34):

You can submit an app with the same name if you change the default language (for example, changing English (US) to English (Canada).

Comment: What if you select English (U.K.) as the default language? Is there any ASO impact?

Answer (score 12):

replace Runner with your app name

Comment: Practically, this is a good answer as we usually forgot to edit the app name because app bundle id is already filled so it gives a sense to mind the only we have to select the language only.

Comment: best answer among all of them!!Thanks

Comment: For those using flutter this is very helpful

Comment: For those who wander what runner, it's a field "Name" on a window that pops up when you are distributing app (where you also choose primary language sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I changed the runner to the app name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Apple also accepts the appeal on it only If you have trademark rights of given name.

> The app name you entered is already being used. If you have trademark rights to this name and would like it released for your use, [submit a claim.](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appnamenotices/)